# Poor mysql 5.7 performance compared to mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have tested alot the last couple of hours and I just can't make mysql 5.7 perform very well

Have tested with a sql dump with single insert statements

In 30 sec mysql 5.7.18 could only import `290 rows` while mysql 5.6.36 could import `470 rows`.. It has been tested on two identical servers.. The server with mysql 5.6 was even a production server with load

- Intel i7 2600
- 16GB RAM
- Tables: InnoDB

## my.cnf for mysql 5.6

```
[client]

# CLIENT #
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]

pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user            = mysql
default-storage-engine  = InnoDB
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir         = /usr
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir     = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size     = 32M
myisam-recover      = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet  = 16M
max-connect-errors  = 1000000
skip-name-resolve
sql-mode        = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
sysdate-is-now      = 1
innodb          = FORCE
innodb-strict-mode  = 1
symbolic-links      = 0
bind_address        = 127.0.0.1

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days    = 10
max_binlog_size     = 100M
sync-binlog     = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size      = 32M
max-heap-table-size = 32M
query-cache-type    = 0
query-cache-size    = 0
max-connections     = 100
thread-cache-size   = 50
open-files-limit    = 65535
table-definition-cache  = 4096
table-open-cache    = 4096

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method     = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group   = 2
innodb-log-file-size        = 256M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit  = 2
innodb-file-per-table       = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size     = 12G

# MARIADB OPTIONS #
# innodb-defragment     = 1
# thread-handling           = pool-of-threads


# LOGGING #
log-error           = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes   = 1
slow-query-log          = 1
slow-query-log-file     = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  = 1
```

## my.cnf for mysql 5.7

```
[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
port                           = 3306
default_storage_engine         = InnoDB
pid-file                       = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# SAFETY #
max_allowed_packet             = 16M
max_connect_errors             = 1000000
skip_name_resolve
sql_mode                       = STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO
sysdate_is_now                 = 1
symbolic_links                 = 0

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
server_id                      = 1
log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
log_slave_updates
expire_logs_days               = 14
sync_binlog                    = 1
log_bin_trust_function_creators= 1
binlog_format                  = ROW

# REPLICATION #
gtid_mode                      = ON
enforce_gtid_consistency

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp_table_size                 = 64M
max_heap_table_size            = 64M
query_cache_type               = 0
query_cache_size               = 0
max_connections                = 500
thread_cache_size              = 50
open_files_limit               = 65535
table_definition_cache         = 4096
table_open_cache               = 4096
wait_timeout                   = 60

# INNODB #
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size           = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size         = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 12G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 8
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode       = 2
innodb_adaptive_hash_index     = 0
innodb_doublewrite             = 0
innodb_change_buffering        = none

# LOGGING #
log_error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time                = 1

basedir                        = /usr
tmpdir                         = /tmp
lc_messages_dir                = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

## Table

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `block_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `account_id_` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `system` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `module` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stock` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_bank` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_monitored` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vatcode_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `ref_currency_id` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sum_account_id_` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `is_dimension` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `accountoff_id` mediumint(7) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `block_id` (`block_id`,`account_id_`),
  KEY `account_id_` (`account_id_`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `system` (`system`),
  KEY `module` (`module`),
  KEY `stock` (`stock`),
  KEY `is_bank` (`is_bank`),
  KEY `is_monitored` (`is_monitored`),
  KEY `vatcode_id` (`vatcode_id`),
  KEY `ref_currency_id` (`ref_currency_id`),
  KEY `sum_account_id_` (`sum_account_id_`),
  KEY `accountoff_id` (`accountoff_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`block_id`) REFERENCES `block` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`ref_currency_id`) REFERENCES `ref_currency` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`vatcode_id`) REFERENCES `vatcode` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`accountoff_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=487803 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci;
```

Comment: Explain "single insert statements" -- One statement with a zillion rows?  Or one row per statement?

Comment: @RickJames one row per statement/query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1` is slower but safer.  This probably explains the difference.

What puzzles me is how it can be so slow as to be only 10 or 15 rows per second.  I would expect 100/sec, even with HDD; much more with SSD.

Would you care to provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a sample row?

Also, what is the `ROW_FORMAT` being used?  Are both InnoDB?

Comment: Ok thanks.. That was it :) There are also alot of indexes on the table.. Its InnoDB

Comment: Have added the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.. When you said there should be 100/sec.. What do you think I could change in the conf to improve perfomance even more?

Comment: After setting `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` mysql 5.7 insert ~600 rows

Comment: Can you bulk your `INSERT`s by grouping many (all) into one transaction?

Comment: Do not "index every column".  Do not index "flags", such indexes won't be used.  Build [_indexes based on SELECTs_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: Yes, a single transaction would significantly help, especially with `= 1`